# Evaluating radio buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to  use the if statement to evaluate the selected radio button. It didn't work, so I'm asking if it's because I did something wrong or because it's not possible in JavaScript.

```
<form name = "f1">
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "Input" onClick="GetSelectedItem(this)">Input
    <input type = "radio" Name = "r1" Value = "Output" onClick ="GetSelectedItem(this)">Output

</form>


<script> 
var output = document.getElementById('output');
function GetSelectedItem(el) {
    output.innerHTML = el.value;
    if(output=="Input") 
       *** do stuff  *** ///
    else  if( output=="output") 
     ** do stuff2 ***

}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no element in the HTML you posted that has the id "output".

Comment: well sould I give each button an id ?

Comment: I think your code is somehow missed up ?
Please check your syntax again or clarify more

Comment: @Engine: No. But if you are trying to get a reference to an element with ID `output` (which you do with `document.getElementById('output');`), than an element with such an ID has to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doable, yes, but you need to fix a few issues:

```
output.innerHTML = el.value;
if(output=="Input")
```

In the if statement, you're actually checking for output, which is the element reference, not it's text or inner HTML. It should be:

```
if(output.innerHTML=="Input")
```

or just (if you're not using the output element for anything else but checking):

```
if(el.value=="Input")
```

See this example:

```js
function GetSelectedItem(el) {
  if (el.value == "Input") {
    alert('input clicked');
  } else if (el.value == "Output") {
    alert('output clicked');
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <input type="radio" Name="r1" Value="Input" onClick="GetSelectedItem(this)">Input
  <input type="radio" Name="r1" Value="Output" onClick="GetSelectedItem(this)">Output

</form>
```

Comment: have to wait 10 min to accept your answer !

Comment: You're welcome! No problem about waiting, you can check the code example in the mean time.

Comment: No problem. Note that you might want to use onchange listeners instead of onclicks because you can also check the buttons using the keyboard or by touching, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote, creep.

Comment: wasn't me , and I really do have an issue with those down votes

Comment: I know it wasn't you, you seem like a nice guy and I'd never call *you* a creep (I upvoted your question long ago). Best of luck on your JS journey! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `el.value`

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function GetSelectedItem(el) {
    output.innerHTML = el.value;

    if (el.value == "Input") {
      alert(el.value);  
    } else if(el.value == "Output") {
      alert(el.value);
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/vehapo/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use == for comparision, rather use === as one checks for just value and the other checks for value and type.

I would write the function like this:

```
<script> 
function GetSelectedItem(el) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML = el.value;
    if( el.value === "Input")
    {
       *** do stuff  *** ///
    }
    else  if(el.value === "output") 
    {
     ** do stuff2 ***
    }    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Generally, this is a good advice, but not that important here because there's nothing that would give different results between the two comparisons when comparing to string literals, like OP does in the question. I mean, there's no other type other than a string that could be evaluated to, say, `"Input"`, right? If it was an empty string or something, then yes, the things could get tricky with a simple comparison by value. :)

Comment: This is ridiculous. You should NEVER use == in javascript coding. See more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Before saying something's ridiculous, think. Read answers on that link, then read my comment, carefully. Then read those answers again, carefully, especially this part and below: `The special case is when you compare a literal with an object that evaluates to the same literal, due to its toString or valueOf method. For example, consider the comparison of a string literal with a string object created by the String constructor.`